# Enforce tag policy for EC2 for Private AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, scp, policy, amazon-ami

I need to restrict users to use few mandatory tags for all ec2 instances launched using private images, but those tags are not mandatory if they use public/marketplace/amazon images.

Let's say tag "Env" is mandatory for each EC2Launch using a private image but not mandatory if using marketplace imagaes.

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyEC2Launch",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunScheduledInstances",
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/Env": ["?*"]                
                },              
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:Owner": [
                        "account_id_of_private_images"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But this is not working and users are able to consume market AMI and also the tag is not enforced for private AMI.

The expectation of policy is -

- **Env tag is mandatory if** user consumes **private AMI** (shared from
  another account)
- **Env tag is not mandatory if** user consumes **amazon
  AMI**.

Comment: "this is not working" - is not specific. Exactly what's happening? How do you test it? How can anyone reproduce your issue - step by step?

Comment: @Marcin To reproduce the problem:
- Create the above SCP under your PrincipalOU the account (private AMI can be hosted in the same account) is associated.
- In that account try to launch EC2 with any Private AMI without tag "Env" - you should get DENY launching EC2 instance and then retry with adding the tag "Env" - EC2 Launch should be successful. [Expected Behavior]
- Again try to launch EC2 with Amazon AMI (Free or any) with or without the tag "Env" and you should be able to launch EC2. [Expected Behavior]

and I am able to launch EC2 in both cases so the policy is not enforced.